How can I add a variant-picker in the Shopify cart drawer for an upsell product?
I’m trying to add a variant picker in the cart drawer section for an upsell product (a cap with two color variants). However, Shopify doesn’t automatically include a variant selector when upselling this product. The default selection is always the “Navy Blue” variant.
I know that some Shopify theme has a component called product_variant_picker, and these are the parameters it accepts:
{% comment %}
Renders product variant picker
Accepts:

product: {Object} product object.
block: {Object} passing the block information.
product_form_id: {String} Id of the product form to which the variant picker is associated.
update_url: {Boolean} whether or not to update the URL when changing variants. If false, the URL isn't updated. Default: true (optional).

Usage:
{% render 'product-variant-picker', product: product, block: block, product_form_id: product_form_id %}
{% endcomment %}

How do I properly integrate the product_variant_picker in the cart drawer section?
What should I pass for the block parameter?
Is there anything else I’m missing that could be preventing the variant options from displaying correctly?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
